# SQL query for changing values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried the following query to change the values of any rows in the wp_usermeta table with meta_value `a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}` to `a:1:{s:3:"user";b:1;}` but nothing seems to happen..

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
SET meta_value = 'a:1:{s:3:"user";b:1;}'
WHERE meta_value = 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}';
```

Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure you have records where meta_value = 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}'  ?  If not, then nothing is exactly what should be happening.

Comment: If MySQL is in [`safe_update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates), you need to specify a primary key constraint in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @ExactaBox: Yup, returns rows when using `SELECT`

Comment: does mysql throws an error?

Comment: @DreamEater: That could be it!

Comment: @Barranka: no errors :(

Comment: @DreamEater: Please provide it as an answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If MySQL is in [**`safe_update`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates), you need to specify a primary key constraint in your WHERE clause.

### From Docs:

> Permit only those **UPDATE** and **DELETE** statements that specify which rows to modify by using key values. If you have set this option in an option file, you can override it by using --safe-updates on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is see if that WHERE clause is returning anything.

Change it to a select query like so and see if returns any rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_value = 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}'
```

Comment: Thanks John, it returned 70,199 rows.